# Cisco 2960-X IP Address

Tags: cisco, routing, switch, cisco-catalyst, management

I want to access my 2960-X on my "*server-network*".

I have configured a network 10.0.0.0/24 (VLAN60) on the Router, which is connected to the switch over a trunkport. Also VLAN 40, 80, 90 is configured on this trunk. VLAN1 (default VLAN on the switch) is 192.168.1.1.

My play is that the switch will get the IP address 10.0.0.200. So I reach the switch without changing the IP of my server. I also want to reach him on every interface in the whole network.

Is the solution that I have to make every Port a trunk Port, which carries VLAN1 and the VLAN(60 or 40 or 80 or 90) ? Which would be definitly not my plan.

Same scenario as the Router, which is reachable through the Gateways configured for the networks. Do I have to connect the Management Port (left side) to one of the Ports on those network?

Comment: I cannot add a comment as I dont have enough rep. Is the switch you have layer3? If so then you can add an SVI (Switched Virtual Interface) per VLAN, so then you can reach it over whichever VLAN you have an SVI (and valid address) on. If it is not a layer3 switch then it will only allow one SVI. So you would need a router to be able to route the packets from one VLAN to the VLAN that the SVI resides on.

Comment: It is not L3, but the Router is. Can the SVI be in the same subnet as the VLAN? I don't think so or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you are trying to do, I would suggest not trying to add multiple IP interfaces on your L2 switch, but rather configure your router so you can route from the server VLAN to VLAN 1 and access the switch on its 192.168.1.1 address.

Comment: That's what I have done. I created a separate vlan for network components now. And my router routes between them.

Answer (score 1):

you need to differentiate between L2 and L3.
If you want to manage your switch from a subnet you will need to create a SVI (most probably the default GW) for that vlan on your switch.
Also be sure to enable management traffic on the vty lines.

Comment: In conclusion, i can't integrate the Switch in the Subnet created on ASA just for management traffic. I will need a additional VLAN/SVI with another IP Range to manage it? Just in dummielanguage!